# Get the value of a disabled textbox with jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there anyway i can get the value of a textbox with jquery?

I have a table the rows are disabled when it reaches a certain status but i need to mouse over a certain field to display the content of that value in a pop up.

This is my code:

```
 $('.TariffName').mouseover(function (e) {
            x = e.pageX;
            y = e.pageY;
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var notes = tr.find('#txtTariffName').val();
            if (notes != "") {
                $("div#TariffWording").css('top', y).css('left', x);
                $("#TariffWording > p").text(notes);
                $('div#TariffWording').show()
            }
            else {
                $('div#TariffWording').hide()
            }

        });
```

Comment: `tr.find('#txtTariffName').val()` can be simplified to `$('#txtTariffName').val()` and it seems to work pretty well on disabled elements: http://jsfiddle.net/RKnU5/. What is your problem?

Comment: Hi thanks for the snippet an example, is made the changes to my code and its still not working, iv put a break point on the start and nothing is hit?

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'readonly' attribute instead of 'disabled' on text inputs.

Comment: Because disabled elements [don't do postback](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12) (via [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4998307/1599229), with a succinct explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4998302/1599229)).

Answer (score 0):

try to use `:disabled`

```
$("input:disabled").val()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/7227gzpk/