# radio buttons checked with jquery not holding proper value on post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have an html form, with some radio buttons that are dynamically set with jquery. This posts back to an asp.net mvc application.

Lets say we have three radio buttons, lets say the value would modelbind to `RadioOption`:

Name
            ID
         Checked?
     Disabled?
     Model Value

- Option1       #opt1             ✓                   ✗                       0
- Option2       #opt2             ✗                    ✗                       1
- Option3       #opt3             ✗                    ✓                      2

and the user picks a separate option which triggers this bit of javascript code:

```
$("#opt1").prop("checked", false);
$("#opt1").prop("disabled", true);

$("#opt2").prop("checked", false);
$("#opt2").prop("disabled", true);

$("#opt3").prop("checked", true);
$("#opt3").prop("disabled", true);
```

which (visibly) shows

Name
            ID
         Checked?
     Disabled?
     Model Value

- Option1       #opt1             ✗                   ✓                      0
- Option2       #opt2             ✗                   ✓                      1
- Option3       #opt3             ✓                  ✓                      2

So the user won't be able to uncheck `opt3`

Now, this all looks good on the page, but when I hit the submit button, and take a look at the Glimpse Model Binding page, the value that comes in for `RadioOption` is not `2` like I would expect, but `0` (the original value)

Is there another way to set these radio buttons that will allow me to receive the right value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the problem that the Option3 field is disabled, so the value won't be in the post back.

Refer to this [Disabled radio button losing value after postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998241/disabled-radio-button-losing-value-after-postback) for more details.